# /etc/hosts , /etc/sysconfig/network and hostname?

Tags: web-server, hostname, hosts

I need to do the hostname changes on a centos server which will serve www.myserver.com

What do I need to do in `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/sysconfig/network` and with the `hostname` command?

In `/etc/sysconfig/network` do I need to write this :

```
HOSTNAME=www.myserver.com
```

or this :

```
HOSTNAME=myserver.com
```

In `/etc/hosts` do I need to write this :

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX     myserver.com
```

or this :

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX     wwww.myserver.com www
```

Do I need to do `sudo hostname www.myserver.com` or `sudo hostname myserver.com`?

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE :

Is there something else that I need to setup about hostname?

Comment: i don't even get why anyone would bother to do this stuff. i see a mention below of using `hostname -f` so i guess you get a properly-functioning `hostname` command, but what else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

/etc/sysconfig/network file is source from which the startup scripts take the arguments for 'hostname' command. And this should be just the machine name, not fully qualified. The domain part is usually defined in the /etc/resolv.conf file.

Assuming the fully qualified host name is 'lemon.example.com' ('www' doesn't look like a good host name to me), then:

- /etc/sysconfig/network: `HOSTNAME=lemon`
- /etc/resolv.conf (along right 'nameserver' entires): `search example.com`
- /etc/hosts (should not be needed if DNS works properly): `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX lemon.example.com lemon`

If everything is properly configured, then `hostname` command will return "lemon" and `hostname -f` will return "lemon.example.com".

In your case it would seem the hostname is 'www' in domain 'myserver.com'… I don't think that is exactly what you want. 'www' may be an alias (DNS CNAME)… if you want it in your /etc/hosts file, then just append it to the line with your IP:

`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX lemon.example.com lemon www.myserver.com`

The settings from /etc/sysconfig/network will be applied after network is restarted. You may set the hostname immediately with the `hostname` command. /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf changes are active immediately (except for applications that keep old data cached).

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network is actual for pre-systemd Linuxes like CentOS 6 (End of life November 30th, 2020) 

/etc/resolv.conf is managed by NetworkManager in modern distributions (don't edit this file manually)

Answer (score 0):

your settings should look like this:

- `/etc/sysconfig/network`: `HOSTNAME=www.myserver.com`
- `/etc/hosts`: `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX     wwww.myserver.com www`

you can also call `hostname`, but this will only change the hostname until you restart your server the next time.

as far as i can remember, these are all changes you have to make.

Comment: If you put the FQDN in /etc/sysconfig/network then the 'hostname' and 'hostname -f' commands will return the same FQDN value. This is not really correct. 'hostname' should ideally simply return the actual hostname.