# setting hostname other than /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, hostname

How do i set the hostname of the machine (Suse 9.2/9.3) ?
the hosts file in /etc/hosts shows a different hostname.
where is the setting else stored other than in the /etc/hosts file ?
changing the /etc/hosts file did not effect the name of the hostmachine (PS1).

this link was no help:
[/etc/hosts , /etc/sysconfig/network and hostname?](https://serverfault.com/questions/118823/etc-hosts-etc-sysconfig-network-and-hostname)

Comment: The docs aren't even online anymore for a distro that old. You could try looking around in YaST, I suppose.

Comment: I think on old suse systems the file is `/etc/HOSTNAME`. In any case, yast ought to know how to do it, because setting the host name is one of the things it was designed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Suse guy myself, but have you updated `/etc/hostname`? Also, in most Linux distributions you'll need to reboot in order to update the hostname system-wide.

(Yes, I know that *technically* you don't need to reboot, but it's often the best way to make sure the change actually sticks)

Comment: there is no hostname file in /etc/sysconfig/network directory. neither are there /etc/nodename nor /etc/hostname.

Answer (score 1):

in /etc/sysconfig/network you should have a hostname= variable
& depending on the OS, you might also have an /etc/nodename or /etc/hostname (i believe it's this one in Suse)
then if your /etc/hosts is good, reboot your host and you should be good

Comment: there is no hostname file in /etc/sysconfig/network directory. neither are there /etc/nodename nor /etc/hostname.